# Can't find the value when initialising a node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm a beginner programmer. Please help. Can't find the value when unwrapping the childNode. Not sure why. Please help, thanks
My code:

```
var someParentNode = SKSpriteNode()
var someChildNode = SKSpriteNode()
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
someParentNode = self.childNode(withName: "someParentNode") as! SKSpriteNode
someChildNode = self.childNode(withName: "someChildNode") as! SKSpriteNode
```

Issue: Gets an error when its unwrapping the childNode (at the last line):

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Not sure why its an error. Like the name of the nodes suggest, childNode is a parent of someParentNode. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First of all you shouldn't don't force unwrap, learn how to implement unwrapping properly. Secondly, there is no way we can help you determine why `self.childnode(...` returns nil from the code you have supplied. There could be any number of reasons why the returned value is nil.

Comment: Have you checked the names are correct, including lower/uppercase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `someParentNode = self.childNode(withName: "someParentNode") as! SKSpriteNodeself.childNode(withName: "someParentNode")` looks for an SKNode with a name "someParentNode". Bear in mind that this is the name you can assign to a node, as in `someNode.name = "xyz"`. It does not refer to the name of the variable in the line `var someParentNode = SKSpriteNode()`. These are two different things.

Since there are no nodes where `node.name == "someParentNode"`, the function `self.childNode(withName: "someParentNode")` returns `nil`. You then do a forced unwrap with `as!`, causing the error.

You don't need to call `someParentNode = self.childNode(withName: "someParentNode") as! SKSpriteNode` in `didMove`, since you have already created a new `SKNode` and assigned this new `SKNode` to `someParentNode` in the first line. So there is no need to assign it a new node anymore.

If you still want to find a node by name, then do `someParentNode.name = "someParentNode"` before calling `self.childNode(withName: "someParentNode")`, but this is not necessary because as explained above, you already created and assigned a new `SKNode` to `someParentNode`. Also, since you declared `someParentNode` outside of any function, it has global scope in your SKScene, and you can therefore access it in any method of that scene. Therefore, there is no need to use a method to look for the node, since you always have access to that node in your scene.

Hope this helps! The same reasoning applies to `someChildNode`

Comment: @swiftBeginner you're welcome. If it helped you, please accept the answer. Thanks!